# Array instantiation calls a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays

When new keyword is encountered in java an object is created and a constructor is called.

So which constructor is called when an array object is created.

Eg int[] a = new int[];

We know that array are Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't use contructors to initialize. If you try to compile `int[] array = new int[10];` you would get something like the below bytecode:

```
bipush 10
newarray int
astore_1
```

On the other hand, the bytecode instructions for `Person p = new Person();` would look like the below (notice the call to `new` and `init` denoting the call to the constructor):

```
new test/Person
dup
invokespecial test/Person/<init>()V
astore_2
```

Hence arrays have their own way of creation in the JVM that is different than creating class objects.